# Capture looping data of a xml in BAM tool.(Business Activity Monitoring)

Tags: biztalk, tracking, biztalk-bam

My Xml looks like this:

```
<parent>
  <loopnode>
     <id>1</id>
  </loopnode>
  <loopnode>
     <id>2</id>
  </loopnode>
  <loopnode>
     <id>3</id>
  </loopnode>
</parent>
```

I want to capture id 1,2,3. Right now when I mapped this schema in tracking profile editor, I am getting id 1.

Is their any way to get all ids.

I am newbie to BAM. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The tracking profile editor of BAM has some known limitations (see below two links). One of which is looping through repeating elements in a schema in a single TPE profile.

- [BAM – Limitation of Tracking Profile Editor (TPE)](https://sandroaspbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/bam-%E2%80%93-limitation-of-tracking-profile-editor-tpe/)
- [MSDN Considerations and Known Issues for TPE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561699.aspx)

One common solution is to use activity relationships for the looped element/structure/node so that each of your `<loopnode>` elements are processed individually in a separate activity. While a single TPE lacks language/features to access elements from each repeated node, a related activity that handles the processing of a repeating node will be called for each repetition allowing you to take whatever action(s) with the data in each.

There are multiple ways to do this. You can do this through BAM API using [Activity Relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578719.aspx) or through the TPE using Folders: [Relationship Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee277358(v=bts.10).aspx) and [Continuation Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee277386(v=bts.10).aspx).

In your case I believe the easiest way would be to use `loopnode\id` as the ContinuationID passed into a Continuation activity, but if your loopnodes are actually more complex than one value you can choose to pass either multiple values or a more complex message.
See [How to Create a Continuation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559486.aspx)

To learn more about BAM, Microsoft has this in-depth guide for learning all about BAM [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd320628(v=bts.10).aspx)